# Trobleshooting slow writes on hpux

Tags: unix, hp-ux, disk-io

Could anyone offer any troubleshooting ideas or pointers on where/how to get more  information on the difference between sys and real time from the output below?

It is my understanding that the command finished processing in the OS in 4 seconds, but then IO where queued and processing and 38.3 seconds (is that right?). It is somewhat a block box at this point to me on how to get some additional details.

```
time prealloc /myfolder/testfile 2147483648

real       42.5
user        0.0
sys         4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing 2 GB to disk on an HP-UX system; this is most likely using spinning disks (physical hard disks).

The system is writing 2GiB / 42s = 51 MB/s which doesn't sound slow to me.

On these systems you can use tools such as `sar`. Use `sar -ud 5` to see CPU and disk usage during your `prealloc` command; you will likely see disk usage pegged at 100%.